# Option to configure Linux kernel to run userspace script when core dump occurs?

Tags: linux, kernel, crash

Is there any option in the kernel compilation or userspace setting to do the above?  I'm looking to add a crash reported to my new embedded Linux system.

Comment: Don't think so. The thing is that if a kernel crash occurs then the state of the system is unknown and it's not safe to run much of anything at all.

Comment: Modified my question to see if I can easily capture crashes of userspace apps instead.

Comment: Run your program in a shell script that checks the exit code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  If you echo a string that starts with a `|` character to `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern`, it will get executed and receive the core dump as input.  More information is available in `man 5 core`.